# How to access the user-scalable zoom state on iOS Web Application?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications

I'd like to retrieve the level or "state" of the zoom when user has scaled web page / application with pinch zoom. I mean retrieving the values set on <meta name="viewport" content="..." />

Initial-scale is 1.0 and if I'd make a request when user hasn't zoomed the viewport yet, that value 1.0 would be returned.

Is there a property or function which has this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found the answer. It's event.scale - passed in gesturestart / gesturechange / gestureend events.